# How to refresh 3D model in a for-loop in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d

I would like to create a 3D model in real time using a for-loop to loop through image frames that come from a live video feed from a webcam.

Currently, I use a pre-recorded video to fill my data arrays through a for-loop and then render a model. In each frame, I determine the X and Y coordinates and X and Y offsets of a circle in the image and add it to their corresponding arrays (There are 4 arrays). I use these arrays to create a circle using the fsurf() function below and stack them to form a tube.

```
fsurf(funx,funy,funz,[0 2*pi min(Z) max(Z)],'linestyle','none');
```

If I moved the code lines related to rendering the model into my current for-loop, how would I refresh the 3d model shown in the popup at the end of each iteration so that I can visually see each layer being added to my model?

I know how to extract snapshots from a live webcam feed through a for-loop but I am currently stuck on this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you try to update the graph handle (`h = fsurf(...)`) properties? you can update `h.XFunction` or `h.YFunction` value for example.

Comment: Try inserting `drawnow` command to the end of the for-loop.